# Using Temporary Value in If Statement to Proceed to Try Catch

Tags: java, if-statement

I need values inputted into the array to be from 1-100 and not any letters. I tried to set up a temporary value that will catch numbers that are not 1-100 before but can not seem to get it to work. I come to problems where the program will close if letters are inputted. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class FocusGroup {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double tempValue = scan.nextDouble();

        if (tempValue > 100 || tempValue < 0) {
            scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Invalid");

        } else {

            while (true) {
                try {

                    double sumFocus = 0;
                    double[] arrayFocus = new double[2];

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        arrayFocus[i] = scan.nextDouble();
                    }
                    for (double num : arrayFocus) {
                        sumFocus = sumFocus + num;
                    }
                }

                catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    scan.nextLine();
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Better create an additional method taking the input in an endless loop and returning it if input is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this... could you elaborate further please?

Comment: You already created an infinite loop (`while(true)`). Just do that again and in it take input, check it and if it is valid `return`. If you don't want an additional method you also `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Wrong User Input Loop until correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894744/java-wrong-user-input-loop-until-correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your catch statements, you use `scan.nextLine()`, but you should use `scan.nextDouble()`, like you do in your main loop. That is, you want to accept doubles as input.
Also, your try/catch syntax seems to be wrong. You want to catch errors that can be caused by user input; therefore, you need to add the code where the user inputs something in the **try** block. See below:

```
try {
            double tempValue = scan.nextDouble();

            //this loop will keep spinning, until tempValue is valid
            while (tempValue > 100d || tempValue < 0d) {
                System.out.println("Invalid. Try again. Range is 0 - 100");
                tempValue = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            //this loop will spin forever (There is nothing to terminate it)
            while (true) {

                double sumFocus = 0;
                double[] arrayFocus = new double[2];

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    arrayFocus[i] = scan.nextDouble();
                }
                for (double num : arrayFocus) {
                    sumFocus = sumFocus + num;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            scan.nextDouble(); //this doesn't do anything. The value is not assigned to any variable
        }
```

With the above code, when the user enters an invalid characters, e.g: an alphabet letter, then the program will stop. Why? Because the catch is outside the endless loop, which makes your program counter move outside the loop and when the code in the catch statement is executed, your program will also terminate as it reached the end.

What you can do, is something like this:

```
static double validValueWithRange(Double min, Double max){
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a valid value for a 'double': ");
   double value;
   try {
       value = s.nextDouble();
       if(value > max || value < min){
         System.out.println("Invalid. Try again. Range is 0 - 100");
         return validValueWithRange(min, max);
       }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
        return validValueWithRange(min, max);
    }

    return value;
}

static double validValue(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a valid value for a 'double': ");
    double value;
    try {
        value = s.nextDouble();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
        return validValue();
    }

    return value;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double tempValue = validValueWithRange(0d, 100d);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Now entering endless while loop");
        double sumFocus = 0;
        double[] arrayFocus = new double[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            arrayFocus[i] = validValue();
        }
        for (double num : arrayFocus) {
            sumFocus = sumFocus + num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I truly appreciate your time and help. I just ran this code but when I typed in a letter the program still closed and I still got stuck in a loop.

Comment: @a.nguy1 As you can see, anyone can make a mistake. I'm sorry for providing a faulty answer. Here is the corrected one. This should work like a charm

Comment: Also updated indentation to make answer more readable. If this helps solve your problem, please consider choosing this as an accepted solution!

Comment: Works great, Thank you!

Comment: If I did wish to use the temporary value as an input into the array, how would I go about doing so in order for the user to only type in two different numbers instead of three?

Comment: Well, I'll let you figure that out on your own! Don't always rely on others on giving you the solution :) happy coding

Answer (score -1):

You just have to put the initialization of the variable in a try and catch block like this:

```
try {
    double tempValue = scan.nextDouble();
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
}
```

Comment: How would I implement the if statement to validate the range with this code?

Comment: This will not do what the OP asked. It will just display an error message and exit. Maybe if you improved your answer to contain more information?