# How to stop the eternal repetition of else? The else function repeats forever in a while (true) loop. Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I want to make a test code - Confirmation that you are not a robot.
I declare a String variable named addauthentication.
Next, I add the if else function. The system will ask you to write the shortest word in your language (in my case, in Armenian). If addauthentication.equals(// that shortest word) - print (you are logged into your account!).

Else
("Please write the word").

The if else function using a while loop will repeat as long as the condition is true.

Suppose my answer was not correct, then the program should display this to me: (Please write a word). But the same phrase runs forever. But, if my first answer were correct, the system would show me this (you are logged into your account!) - and yes, there were no problems with this thought. How can I correct my code so that after an incorrect answer, I could enter the correct one, and the phrase (Please write a word) is not repeated?

My code is very light, it seemed there shouldn't have been any errors. And in particular, I cannot find the answers to my question in StackOverFlow, so I was forced to ask you my question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class RobotTest2 {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        String addauthentication;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
           
        System.out.println("Confirm with action, that you are not a robot. Write the shortest word in your language.");
        addauthentication = obj.next();
    
        while (true) {
            if (addauthentication.equals("և")) {
                System.out.println("You are logged into your account!");
            } else  
                System.out.println("Please, write a word.");
            }
        }   
    }



My expected result:

    > Confirm with action, that you are not a robot. Write the shortest word in your language.
    > 
    > // user input "և"
    > 
    > You are logged into your account!






//other way

    

> > Confirm with action, that you are not a robot. Write the shortest word in your language.
>     > 
>     > // user input //wrong answer
>     > 
>     > Please write a word. 
>     //user input ("right answer")
>     "You are logged into you account!"



The real result:

   

>  > Confirm with action, that you are not a robot. Write the shortest word in your language.
>     > 
>     > // user input "և"
>     > 
>     > You are logged into your account!




//Other way

    

> > >  Confirm with action, that you are not a robot. Write the shortest word in your language.
> >     
> >              //user input 
> >             //wrong answer 
> >             
>              "Please write a word." 
>          "Please write a word." 
>          "Please write a word." 
>          "Please write a word." 
>          "Please write a word." 
>          "Please write a word." 
>         ......

//And so, the same phrase repeats forever.
```

Comment: You forgot to `break` from the loop when the `if` condition is true.

Comment: As an aside: "My code is very light, it seemed there shouldn't have been any errors." shortness does not imply correctness.

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894744/java-wrong-user-input-loop-until-correct) on how to ask input until it's correct.

Comment: Do `addauthentication = obj.next();` only inside the while, and `break` in the if-then part. Too light code is also ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if I understood well, you want to stay in the loop until the user gives the correct answer. And you don't want "Please write a word" to be shown forever.
This is happening because you're reading only once from the console (outside the loop) so the exact same string is evaluating over and over again, if it was wrong the first time, it'll keep wrong.
So my suggestion is to read inside the loop, so you'll check the answer in every iteration.

```
while (true) {
    addauthentication = obj.next();
    if (addauthentication.equals("և")){
        System.out.println("You are logged into your account!");
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please, write a word.");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added a `break` in order to exit the loop whenever the user hits the right answer.